# How to restart listening Twitter straming Api Again?

Tags: twitter-streaming-api

I'm using Twitter4j to get Tweets real time via. Twitter streaming API and it is working fine . Sometime it throws Exception due to network connecting issue(or some other reason) which is also OK to me however I'm not able to recover from this condition & it require server restart . Can someone please suggest how to restart  listening Twitter straming Api Again without server restart . We have TwitterStreamFactory & TwitterStream class in Twitter4j. Many thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a handler for such exceptions and in it create a loop that tries to start listening a few times before erroring out.